# How do I use normalizr and/or immutablejs to create normalized data structure

Tags: javascript, normalizr

I have an unruly chunk of data being returned from a client API. **I do not have the ability to have them change it, they've made that clear**.

```
{
"feed": {
    "name": "name",
    "media:destination": "http...",
    "channel": {
        "pagecomponent": {
            "component": [{
                "item": {
                    "link": "http...",
                    "description": "description",
                    "title": "title",
                    "category": "tag 2",
                    "pubDate": "2002-01-01T20:00:00.000Z",
                    "media:content": {
                        "medium": "image",
                        "url": "http..."
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "item": {
                    "link": "",
                    "info:pagecomponent": {
                        "id": "1237",
                        "content": "na"
                    },
                    "description": "description",
                    "title": "title",
                    "category": "tag 1",
                    "pubDate": "2007-01-21T20:00:00.000Z",
                    "media:content": {
                        "media:restriction": [{
                            "relationship": "allow",
                            "type": "country",
                            "content": "us ca"
                        }, {
                            "relationship": "allow",
                            "type": "url",
                            "content": "?"
                        }],
                        "media:description": "title",
                        "media:thumbnail": {
                            "width": "",
                            "url": "http...",
                            "height": ""
                        },
                        "media:title": "title",
                        "medium": "video",
                        "type": "application/x-mpegURL",
                        "url": "http..."
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the first few layers never change and have zero effect on the UI. I've tried several variations of using normalizr, but nothing remotely works. The data that's important to me is at the "component" level. Ultimately, the only data I care about is in the array of "items" from the "component" key:

```
item: {
    id: null,
    link: null,
    description: null,
    title: null,
    pubDate: null,
    category: null,
    thumbnailWidth: null,
    thumbnailUrl: null,
    thumbnailHeight: null,
    medium: null,
    contentTypeHeader: null,
    videoUrl: null,
    "media:content": mediaInfo,
    "media:restriction": restrictions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It hardly seems like a library like normalizr is necessary in this case.

Just use `JSON.parse` to turn the JSON string into an object, navigate the hierarchy until you get to the `component` array, and map each element to its `item` property.

```js
// for demo purposes; I expect you already have this variable
var json = document.getElementById('json').value

var data = JSON.parse(json.trim())

var items = data.feed.channel.pagecomponent.component.map(function (e) { return e.item })

console.log(items)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<pre id="json" style="display:none">
{
"feed": {
    "name": "name",
    "media:destination": "http...",
    "channel": {
        "pagecomponent": {
            "component": [{
                "item": {
                    "link": "http...",
                    "description": "description",
                    "title": "title",
                    "category": "tag 2",
                    "pubDate": "2002-01-01T20:00:00.000Z",
                    "media:content": {
                        "medium": "image",
                        "url": "http..."
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "item": {
                    "link": "",
                    "info:pagecomponent": {
                        "id": "1237",
                        "content": "na"
                    },
                    "description": "description",
                    "title": "title",
                    "category": "tag 1",
                    "pubDate": "2007-01-21T20:00:00.000Z",
                    "media:content": {
                        "media:restriction": [{
                            "relationship": "allow",
                            "type": "country",
                            "content": "us ca"
                        }, {
                            "relationship": "allow",
                            "type": "url",
                            "content": "?"
                        }],
                        "media:description": "title",
                        "media:thumbnail": {
                            "width": "",
                            "url": "http...",
                            "height": ""
                        },
                        "media:title": "title",
                        "medium": "video",
                        "type": "application/x-mpegURL",
                        "url": "http..."
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
}
</pre>
```

Comment: This looks like the best way to approach first. Normalizr is great for nested data (where you might have entities within entities). The data given looks like the only issue is that the data you want happens to be deeper than the top level. ImmutableJS isn't going to do anything for what you're asking.